# How to check,has the user already authenticated the application or it has to be authenticated via Linkedin api?

Tags: api, popup, linkedin-api

How can i check has the user already authenticated the application or it has to be authenticated via Linkedin javascript api ?

My problem is,if user hasn't authenticated the application he can do that by clicking on a checkbox that initiates popup for linkedin app authentication  without using the predefined linkedin button  ?

- how can i show this script in popup,not using the linkedin button ?

Answer (score 0):

Load the [JavaScript API](https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/javascript-api-reference-0), then make a call to `IN.User.isAuthorized()`

https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/inauth-inevent-and-inui

If the user has not authorized, when they click the checkbox you can open the authorization popup with a call to `IN.UI.Authorize().place()`